# Debugging cucumber steps in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, cucumber, webstorm, webdriver-io

I'm experimenting with `Cucumber/WebdriverIO UI` tests using Webstorm (NodeJs platform). At certain steps I would really love to stop it in **debug** mode, check the retrieved element and see what can I do with it.

But unfortunately the **Debug** button is disabled and I couldn't find anything specific in `Webstorm` documentation as well.

If I can achieve my original goal (stopping a step and experimenting with the elements) without using Webstorm's **Debug** mode, that's totally fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging Cucumber specs is not currently supported, please vote for [WEB-15146](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15146)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this would work with Cucumber but WebdriverIO now has a [debug](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/debug.html) command you can use